# Is it possible to craft a crystal similar to the Truedeath one, but for creatures with the Plant type?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting, sneak-attack, critical-hit

Is it possible to craft a crystal similar to the Truedeath one, but for [Plants](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#plantType)?

**Truedeath Crystal** (Greater) and **Demolition Crystal** (Greater) are Weapon Augment Crystals (*Magic Item Compendium*, p.65-66) that let you deliver critical hits and sneak attacks respectively to Undeads and Constructs.

To craft a Truedeath Crystal the [Consacrate](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/consecrate.htm) (*Player's Handbook v.3.5*, p. 212) spell is required and [Disintegrate](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/disintegrate.htm) (*Player's Handbook v.3.5*, p. 222) has to be used to create a Demolition Crystal.

First question:

1. Which spell could be selected as prerequisite to craft a sort of Vinestrike* Crystal?

---

*similar to the Vine Strike (*Spell Compendium*, p. 230) spell

---

The other thing is: Lesser crystals have "unique" abilities, while Least and Greater seem to be standardized.

> DEMOLITION CRYSTAL

> [...]

> **Least**: A weapon with this crystal attached deals an extra 1d6 points of damage to constructs.

> **Lesser**: As the least crystal, and the weapon is treated as adamantine for the purpose of overcoming the damage reduction of constructs.

> **Greater**: As the lesser crystal, and the weapon can deliver sneak attacks and critical hits against constructs as if they were living creatures.

*and*

> TRUEDEATH CRYSTAL

> [...]

> **Least**: A weapon with this crystal attached deals an extra 1d6 points of damage to undead.

> **Lesser**: As the least crystal, and the weapon also functions as a ghost touch weapon (DMG 224).

> **Greater**: As the lesser crystal, and the weapon can deliver sneak attacks and critical hits against undead as if they were living creatures.

*so*:

2. What kind of ability a lesser crystal could grant?

---

Comment: How would we judge answers right or wrong? If these items needs to be home brewed, the only "answer" would be the good old "your DM decides" but that's not really useful. Or are you a DM at that table?

Comment: @Molot yes, it could be a "your DM decides" type of question. No, I am not the DM at the table, I am one of the players. I haven't thought that this could not be the place to discuss a homebrew topic, should I delete it and post it in a forum maybe?

Comment: Or, would it be different if I re-write the question? Something like "Is this homebrew Weapon Augment Crystal balanced?"

Comment: Homebrew *review* is on topic and answerable. Homebrew *generation* is much harder to fit into the format and rules of this site. I'm not telling you to delete because maybe it can be good fit, or maybe others think it already is good enough? It is an interesting topic and well written text, I'm just afraid it's hard to answer objectively and somewhat universally. But so far that's just me.

Comment: @Mołot As always, the primary goal is “can voters judge the answers?” and for that, they can judge answers much as they would judge any other homebrew, e.g. in a homebrew-review question. Backing up decisions by referencing existing material, or better, personal experience having used it, would be the kinds of things voters should look for. This is exactly the kind of question that the Stack Exchange format frankly **excels** at, because all answers are *not* going to be equally-good and experts can judge that. Where else are you going to find such expertise, particularly with so little noise?

Comment: @Mołot *Often* a question asking for homebrew could very well reasonably be closed as too-broad, so you’re certainly not wholly wrong. But in this case, we are talking about a very narrow thing, one minor magic item that parallels several similar items. I don’t think either of the existing answers are over-long, or at their current length too brief to cover everything that needs covering.

Answer (score 4):

We can't tell you what sort of rulings your DM should issue.  This is especially complicated because the two crystals you cite seem to have very different costs: the *greater truedeath crystal* costs 10000gp (5000gp more than the *lesser truedeath crystal*), but the *greater demolition crystal* costs 6000gp (3000gp more than the *lesser demolition crystal*), even though the upgrades do the same thing.  I suspect the price difference is because undead are more common than constructs.  Plants are fairly uncommon in most games, but it will be up to your DM to rule on how much this crystal should cost in your own game.

If you're looking for a spell to serve as a prerequisite, the obvious choice would be [blight](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/blight.htm), which damages plant creatures and destroys plant that are not creatures.

Lesser abilities of the other crystals seem to be focused on bypassing the defenses of undead or construct creatures.  Unfortunately plants don't seem to have a consistent theme for defenses.  For example, the Treant has DR 10/slashing, but the Tendriculos has regeneration which can be pierced by bludgeoning, and the Assassin Vine has neither.  If I were designing this homebrew item, I wouldn't create a "lesser" crystal at all since there's not a good analog; I'd start with the "least" crystal and go straight to the "greater" crystal, and have it be priced slightly cheaper as a result.

Comment: Skipping the *lesser crystal* is a pretty darn good call, +1.

Answer (score 2):

*Consecrate* is a 2nd-level spell and *disintegrate* is a 6th-level spell, which is totally bonkers as far as I can tell. Undead tend to be the more common threat in most campaigns, making the *truedeath* crystal more valuable, not less. Of course, their costs reflect that, with *truedeath* being substantially more expensive (at the lesser and greater tiers), but it’s bizarre to put off being able to craft *demolition* crystals for 8 levels.

My point is that the existing crystals’ prerequisites are already not very well balanced. That gives us a lot of room to kind of do whatever we want—it’s not likely to be **worse** that what we’ve already got. *Blight* is a quintessential anti-plant spell, and as a 4th-level spell it’s nicely in the middle, so that could work. I certainly doubt you’re likely to find any other spell that deals directly with plants and is nearly as iconic—I guess *horrid wilting*, but that’s 8th-level which seems quite unnecessary.

Personally, though, my inclination would be to simply use *gravestrike*, *golemstrike*, and *vinestrike* as the required spells for these crystals. Those spells are far closer to what the crystals do than the official ones, after all, and they’re the same level, which is appropriate for crystals that do roughly the same thing. The costs on the crystals already provide plenty of “level gate” on them, so requiring lower-level spells isn’t really going to make them available earlier, either.

As for what to do with such a *lesser crystal of wilting* should do, that’s far more tricky: DR is a very common defense for constructs, and incorporeality is almost exclusively found among the undead. Plant creatures aren’t that common, and don’t have any obvious, iconic defense to consider beyond their immunity to critical hits. For example, there are only seven plant creatures in *Monster Manual*, and the only particular special defense beyond plant traits found on more than one of them is immunity to electricity (which both assassin vines and shambling mounds have, shambling mounds famously instead gaining Constitution when subject to electricity damage). Otherwise, we have invisibility (phantom fungus), regeneration (tendriculos), DR 10/slashing (treant), and nothing much in particular (shrieker and violet fungus). And some assorted, inconsistent elemental resistances.

Ignoring elemental resistances on the weapon’s attacks against plants might be viable—after all, elemental-damage special properties are reasonably popular—but it’s pretty weird to me, since it’s not automatically something a weapon attack is necessarily going to care about and it’s also not something particularly iconic to plants, despite several of them having some. Still, ignoring a shambling mound’s immunity to electricity is directly bypassing one of its most famous defenses, and the shambling mound is probably the most iconic D&D plant monster.

And honestly, I can’t think of anything else. Maybe something with *Sandstorm*’s dessication damage? A d6 of dessication damage becomes a d8 when targeting a plant (or water elemental) creature, so that’s something. Maybe instead ignoring elemental resistances, convert elemental damage to dessication, and up the die size one, when attacking plants?

Oh, one thing you might do is cause the weapon to be more usable or useful in a grapple—plants often have grasping vines and the like. Maybe if you have the weapon drawn while grappling a plant creature, you get some constrict damage? Balancing that would be trickier—more than I’m able to suggest in this answer—but I kind of like the idea.

Really, though, I like [Dan B’s suggestion to just ditch the *lesser* crystal altogether](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/169568/4563)—wish I’d thought of that. It’s almost-certainly the better call. I would probably go with eliminating the *greater crystal* though—since you’re eliminating an extra feature (as the *greater crystal* for the other two includes the *lesser crystal*), and plants are way less common as enemies, the ability to score critical hits against them is less valuable, and less worth meeting a *greater crystal*’s requirements.